# how can I code a nanosecond countdowntimer?

Tags: android

I have a nanotimer but it can only count up. I need a timer that counts down from, let's say 10000 nanoseconds. I hope somebody can help me with that. Thanks.

```
TextView txtTimer;
Handler costumHandler = new Handler();
long startTime = 0L, timeInMilliseconds=0L, timeSwapBuff = 0L, updateTime = 0L;

Runnable updateTimerThread=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
        updateTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
        int secs = (int) (updateTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs %= 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updateTime % 1000);
        txtTimer.setText(String.format("%02d", secs) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        costumHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
    }
};
```

I now have a timer that starts when the user presses the screen and when you reach a number of taps on the screen, it will stop but I'd like the nanotimer to count down instead. I hope somebody can help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! SO works a little differently than other forums as we expect that you attempt to solve the problem first on your own. If you are still facing specific issues, please edit your question and add details about the problems you are facing and we will be happy to help. Also, have a look at [this help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers :)

Comment: ok thanks  for your reply yes i try to solve it but no way i have  realy no idea how to solve it but thanks for the link i will check it

Comment: If `up` is counting up, then `10000 - up` is counting down from 10000.

Comment: Henry   yes your right but i got still a - on the display how to gemover that one?

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution i know my gramatica is very bad:)

this is the source to count down the timer thanks for reply

enter code hereenter code here

```
 long startTime=0L,timeInMilliseconds=0L,timeSwapBuff=10000L,updateTime=0L;

    Runnable updateTimerThread=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds=-(SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-startTime);
        updateTime=timeSwapBuff+timeInMilliseconds;
        int secs=(int)(updateTime/1000);

        int mins=secs/60;
        secs%=60;
        int milliseconds =(int)(updateTime%1000);
        txtTimer.setText(String.format("%02d",secs)+":"+String.format("%03d",milliseconds));
        costumHandler.postDelayed(this,0);
        System.out.println(updateTime);
    }
};
```